# "There can only be one IDENTITY column per table" - Why?

Tags: sql-server, identity-column, database-design

*"There can only be one IDENTITY column per table"*

Why is it so? Take a scenario of a vehicle, there exists a chasis number which is unique as well as the registration number which turns out to be unique. To depict this scenario in ***sql server*** we need a custom implementation for on of the columns. Conversely, in ***Oracle*** you can have as many sequences as you want on a table. Why is there a restriction on the IDENTITY Column, any specific reasons?

The scenario of having a vehicle schema is something imaginary am questioning myself as to why there's a restriction on the identity column.

Comment: I want to know why it is not possible.

Comment: Because the engineers on the SQL Server team either couldn't do it, or didn't think it was a good idea to do it.

Comment: PostgreSQL also [thankfully] has sequences, and I agree they are a better approach than IDENTITY (and MySQL's auto_increment for that matter).  Why doesn't SQL Server support this?  I'd figure it's a throwback to the Sybase code SQL Server was based on, but that whomever built that code never encountered the need.  I admit, the need is very corner case.

Comment: Sounds like somebody is abdicating the implementation of requirements to SqlServer.

Comment: For your vehicle example, bear in mind that the **chassis number** will be an attribute of the vehicle, but the **registration** will be an attribute of the owner, which is an attribute of the vehicle.  Normalization works!

Comment: @JNK: Yes normalization works, Suppose there's a User schema (with registration as the PK) and another details schema with Chasis number as the PK and the registration number as the FK. In a city lets suppose there are 100K vehicles and I need to store the information of all the vehicles, so i have a user schema and details schema each with 100K rows. then whats the cost of joins that will be incurred when normalization principle is followed? Will that not be heavy?

Comment: @Chaitanya - It won't be terrible if your indexes are properly applied.  Also bear in mind that you are precluding anyone from owning more than one vehicle in your design.  Ideally the vehicle will have an ID, the owner will have an ID, and you will have more flexibility to model real-world situations.  I guess this will depend on whether you want your data to fit the real world, or the real world to mold to your data model...

Comment: @JNK: Am a beginner in designing tables and with a lot of stuff around on designing schema's, am confused on how to look at the things. This caused me to ask the question, the table i'm designing falls very much into this scenario. I apologize if i have acted ignorantly & incoherently. The whole intention is to know the correct method[process] to go about designing schema's.

Comment: @Chaitanya - no need to apologize, this is how people learn things.  I am far from an expert but wanted to point out to you what I thought was an oversight in  your analogy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An Identity Column in SQL Server has a seed and an auto increment. We could always calculate what the 2nd hypothetical id value should be if we knew the value of the first id column anyway.

e.g. If this was legal syntax

```
create table #foo
(
bar int identity(1,10),
baz int identity(1000,1)
)
```

We wouldn't need to store baz as it could be calculated from bar as follows.

```
baz = 1000 + (bar-1)/10
```

Comment: darn you for articulating what i was trying to say!

Comment: very late but, what if `bar` is guid and `baz` is int?

Comment: @ibubi [`IDENTITY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017) in SQL Server is always some sort of integer. You can't declare a guid column with `IDENTITY` property.

Answer (score 6):

Because it's would be the same value.  if you had identity(1,1) as the primary, and identity(100,2), you would get these results:

```
1     100
2     102
3     104
4     106
5     108
6     110
7     112
8     114
9     116
10    118
```

you could get the second column by doing this:

((ID-1)*2)+100

it's a linear equation, so what would be the point other than for show?

Comment: IDENTITY values are not always assigned in sequence however. If you have two simultaneous inserts of multiple rows then the values can get interleaved between the two sets of rows. Also, specific values could be inserted so that the two columns aren't dependent on each other. Just a couple of reasons why you might want two IDENTITY columns.

Comment: @dportas, sure, but in theory, if you had 2 identities, they would both be assigned at the same time, still giving you the same effect.

Comment: Excellent answer!

Answer (score 2):

Data is stored in the database, keyed by the `IDENTITY` column.  A single such column allows for a filesystem-like storage.  Having multiple `IDENTITY` columns would confuse the issue.

My recommendation is to choose one of your columns to be the `IDENTITY` or `PRIMARY KEY`, and for the other to be a `UNIQUE KEY`.  As a user there will be no difference, but it will make the DBMS happy.

Answer (score 1):

- Oracle sequences are not SQL Server IDENTITY columns: you write some code for them. They don't work out of the box based on the CREATE TABLE DDL
- **Any** subsequent IDENTITY columns can be worked out from the first one (edit: as other folk mentioned)

Answer (score 1):

The reason isn't explained in MSDN that I could find. However, I suspect that it has to do with the way sql server implements the identity column. Conceptually, I think it's more a setting or value at the table level than at the column level and the column is just a way to access the value. I think this because all the methods for interacting with identity values have the table as a parameter and not the column eg. IDENT_SEED, IDENT_CURRENT, and IDENT_INCR. If it was a column level setting, the parameters would include a column name. If you had more than one identity column on the table, those functions wouldn't work.

I'm just speculating though.

Answer (score 0):

It's a silly limitation I agree. It's not too difficult to work around it though. Just create a separate table with an IDENTITY column to use purely as a sequence generator. Insert into the sequence table, retrieve the value using SCOPE_IDENTITY() and then insert the value wherever you like. You can then support as many sequences as you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a **computed** column instead, starting at some value plus the id value:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TwoIdentity (id INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL, SecondID AS 100+id, TEXT VARCHAR(50) NULL)
```

[image]