# Column alias on table declaration

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Is there a way, in Oracle 11gR2 that I could create *a single column with two names*?

Reason I need this is back compatibility, on situations in which this would work:

```
create table test1 (col1 varchar2(10), col2 [some ref to col1]);

insert into test1 values ('test_value');
```

and then

```
SQL> select col1 from test1;
test_value

SQL> select col2 from test1;
test_value
```

There seem to be a way of thing so on [*SQL Server*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4491581/323129), I am looking for the Oracle equivalent to it.

ideas?

Comment: Is creating a `view` not enough?

Comment: cant.. would have two objects with the same name. also, due to other constrains, I couldn't rename the "original"

Comment: Not if in different schema

Comment: well, this would all be in the same schema.

Comment: Another method would be to use Edition-Based Redefinition - you rename the table e.g. test1$base and then create edition-based views, one for each client. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_editions.htm - this would then allow you to use Edition triggers to transform data from both applications seemlessly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `VIRTUAL COLUMN`:

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (
  col1 VARCHAR2(10),
  col2 VARCHAR2(10) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (col1 || '')
);

INSERT INTO test1 (col1) VALUES ('test_value');
COMMIT;

SELECT * FROM test1;

COL1       COL2     
---------- ----------
test_value test_value
```

However, virtual columns cannot be manipulated by DML. Read more here: [Oracle Base - Virtual Columns](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1.php)