# Have you tried to use SQLite as the query engine for your *raw* database?

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, reporting

I have made a custom report generator for *our* database ([Oracle Berkeley DB](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/berkeley-db/db/index.html) engine).
 Now it's time for me to add more flexibility and I am in dilemma. Do a partial or a fundamental redesign?

1. Lets assume that I have plenty of time.
2. I can only read the database, I don't have the right to modify it.

Inspired from [Query Anything with SQLite](http://www.ddj.com/database/202802959) article, I would like to let [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) engine to do the *dirty* work (grouping, filtering, etc).

Have you tried it? Any examples? What about performance issues?

Comment: So you want to create a virtual sqlite table 'filled' with data from your Oracle Berkeley DB?  Very ambitious!

Comment: If I am not wrong, I don't have to fill tables just use *intermidiate* values. Actually thats why I ask before I try it. I am not sure how to tackle it :)

Comment: The virtual table will act like a view on the Oracle Berkeley DB? Is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: Not like a view. Somehow, SQLite will use my callbacks instead of the built-in *table walk* routines, while querying a virtual table.

Answer (score 1):

It works fine for what I am using it :-) However I don't use it together with another database, just standalone. There's a list of [Well-known Users](http://www.sqlite.org/famous.html) of SQlite on their website.

You need to tell us more about your usecase to make any speculations about performance, but I'd rather make a POC and measure performance [Long-held, incorrect programming assumptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888224/what-is-your-longest-held-programming-assumption-that-turned-out-to-be-incorrect/888766#888766)

There is a nice [quickstart](http://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html) article on the [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org) site.

Here's the [C/C++ API Reference](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/intro.html).

I assume you should be able to create a temporary SQLite table by initially querying your other DB and inserting the data into the temporary SQLite table. Then you can use different querys on that temporary table to do your grouping, filtering, etc.

Comment: I'm familiar with SQLite3 :) In the database are stored raw data/tables. I want to fetch data through sqlite and queries.

Comment: @tydoc OK your "Have you tried it?" made me think you don't know SQLite (yet) ;-)

Comment: "I assume you should be able to create...". I have thought that already, and it is exactly what I want to avoid :) It's a nice solution but I don't want to create extra tables because the database can have thousands of records, ie OrderLines.

Comment: @tydok Maybe you need to clarify what you exactly want to do. If you issue a query to your db that e.g. returns 10000 rows, then you can query your other DB only once and store the result set in a temp SQLite table and then use further (SQLite) queries to sort/filter these results. And from your question I assumed that's exactly what you planned to do.