# Why can clone set a private field on another object?

Tags: java, private, access-modifiers

I'm learning Java, and the book I'm reading has the following example on cloning. In `clone()`, my first instance is able to set buffer on the new object even though buffer is `private`. It seems like it should require the field to be `protected` for this to work.

Why is this allowed? Does `clone()` have special privileges that allows it to access the `private` fields?

```
public class IntegerStack implements Cloneable {
    private int[] buffer;
    private int top;

    // ... code omitted ...

    @Override
    public IntegerStack clone() {
        try{
            IntegerStack nObj = (IntegerStack) super.clone();
            nObj.buffer = buffer.clone();
            return nObj;
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e)
        {
            throw new InternalError(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `private` modifier does not mean that only the same instance can access the field; it means only objects of the same class can access it.

The [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html) says in [§6.6, Access Control](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.6):

> ... if the member or constructor is declared private, then access is permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level class [(§7.6)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#26783) that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor.

In other words, anything inside the class can access it at any time. Even nested classes can access `private` members and constructors in the enclosing class, and vice versa.

(You're not alone in misunderstanding it; check out [this much-upvoted answer to "What is your longest-held programming assumption that turned out to be incorrect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888224/what-is-your-longest-held-programming-assumption-that-turned-out-to-be-incorrect/888246#888246))

Comment: thanks! I also know PHP, so I've verified that PHP's version of private actually works the same way.

Comment: I think most object-oriented languages work this way. I know C# and C++ do. Apparently Ruby and VB6 have instance-private variables, and Scale can do `private[this]`, but that's all I know of that work the other way. (I only know about Ruby, VB6, and Scala from the comments in the linked answer.)