# SOLID principles or none SOLID

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, solid-principles, design-principles

I am continuing the development of an ASP.NET application (web form based) where the previous developer did not follow principles of good Object Oriented design i.e. SOLID (http://www.remondo.net/solid-principles-csharp-interface-segregation/).  I have read posts like this: [Long-held, incorrect programming assumptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888224/long-held-incorrect-programming-assumptions/889625#889625).

The problem is that a lot of the classes have low cohesion and are highly coupled and a lot of the classes do not have a single responsibility (they have many).  My specific question is: should I start following the SOLID principles or just continue developing by tweeking and adding more to the classes? I have always tried to follow principles like SOLID in the past, but the application I am talking about is very large and complex.  I am the only developer working on this project.

A complete rewrite is out of the question at the moment but will be possible one day.

**Update 15/07/2012**
So far I have discovered that SOLID is a design principle and GRASP is a design pattern, which is perhaps more suitable to MVC rather than a Page Controller type application.  Mock objects are also perhaps more suited to MVC according to this link: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/overview/asp-net-mvc-overview.  Based on the response so far it is always good practice to follow SOLID principles.  However, the answers so far do not recommend design patterns for form based apps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try refactoring bit by bit.

If you are working on a module, try adding a few interfaces here and there ;-) as you go. Any new code that you write should be SOLID. Try encapsulating old code as much as possible, put old crap behind a facade. You don't have to rewrite it right now, maybe never. As long as you can encapsulate old code behind a facade and write unit tests for the facade you should feel a lot better.

Example: So lets say you have a collection of classes that implement some piece of functionality, ie. invoice processing. Right now I imagine those classes are used in many places and there is a lot of duplication going on. The code for calculating total invoice amount is copied on every page that displays it. What I would do in that case is to create an Invoice service which will expose methods for getting an invoice, adding new lines, calculating total amount, etc. You can than put the code that you have in this service without much refactoring, you will keep the same db schema and so on. But from now on your pages will interact only with `IInvoiceService` interface and you can mock it nicely. It is a bit of 'swiping dust under the carpet' but at least you can stop the crap spreading even further. Next time you need to do something in the invoicing module (fix a bug, implement new feature) you clean the existing code a bit. Over time the amount of dust under the carpet gets smaller and smaller. You just need to stick to your guns and make sure that the service interface stays nice and clean.

You may need to make some more system-wide changes, like introducing DI framework, but try keeping the changes to minimal. Usually when you start going to far you can easily find yourself rewriting everything, and you don't want that.

Make small changes, commit often.

Comment: +1 for the reference to DI framework.  I have not heard of this.  Could you elaborate on what you mean by:"put old crap behind a facade?"

Comment: Updated an answer with an example.

Comment: Most of the .net code is in one place.  There is VB6 and C++ code.  This is often duplicated i.e. VB6 code appears in the .NET app and C++ code appears in the VB6 app.

Comment: The research I have done suggests that the DI framework is better for MVC based applications rather than form based applications.

Comment: IMHO DI is a good way to improve maintainability of the code regardless of the kind of application you're building. I've successfully used DI in MVC, WebForms, WinForms and Windows Services.

Answer (score 0):

It's like asking "Well, I just bought an apartment from someone but there's dirt everywhere. Should I clean it up or just leave it as is?"

The answer is obvious. You said the application is complex. If it is complex just because of the bad architecture - there's your chance to make it more understandable. It it is complex because of the nature of the bussiness issue, the bad architecture just makes it worse.

SOLID are very important principles. Also pay attention to GRASP guidelines, I guess you do so because you mention low coupling and high cohesion and these belong to GRASP rather than to SOLID.

The most obvious approach is to refactor, step by step in a right direction. Decouple classes, define their responsibilities, make them more cohesive, introduce interfaces and code against them. These are much more important than SOLID's Open-Closed Principle or Liskov Substitution Principle.

Comment: Thanks.  Your first sentence does make sense, but I think it is a matter of priorities.  There is still a lot to do and the priority is to get it done.  If I had more time then I would refactor all of the code.

Comment: True, priorities are important. The truth is that your clients probably do not care much about architecture, they just want things to be done. However, the longer you leave the mess untouched, the slower you are in introducing new features. If you are working alone, this can be not really important. However, if you have a team behind you, you all have an unwanted burden that slows you down.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to pick a feature and start unit testing it and introduce a mock library such as Moq or FakeItEasy.

I completely understand this is a handed over code for you. But with unit testing you will come to know what code is a good candidate for Single Responsibility or must be a Service or must be moved in a Repository.

You are already going to implement DI, but also use something like AutoMapper saves you alot of time and keeps the code smaller and clearer

When I was handed over like your situation the very thing I did is read Uncle Bob,s book http://www.amazon.co.uk/Working-Effectively-Legacy-Robert-Martin/dp/0131177052 it gives you some good ideas

**Update on your comment:**
The app after first 3 months have less bugs and a bit easier & quicker to implement new changes. The best part is that now we have the domain knowledge. One good thing that stopped legacy and new changes causing bugs was Anit-Corruption layer please read this link http://domaindrivendesign.org/library/peng_hu_2007_2

Comment: thanks.  How does you app look now? How long have you been working on it?

Comment: The reading I have done suggests that Mock libraries and DI is more suitable for MVC based applications rather than Windows forms.  Do you agree? Please see here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/overview/asp-net-mvc-overview

Comment: @w0051977 the article is saying the MVC framework have all the features in it

Comment: Is it not possible to use these features with web Forms/windows forms? i.e. do forms have "all the features in it"

Comment: Yes you can these are separate framwework Unity is for DI, NUnit for unit testing, Moq for mocking and AutoMapper for mapping objects

Answer (score 0):

I've worked in a shop that had good unit test code coverage (over 3000 tests), which the writing thereof encouraged our code to generally follow the SOLID principles.

I've also worked in a shop with 0% code coverage (circa 0.5m lines of code), which didn't adopt SOLID in the slightest.

We couldn't refactor any of the half million lines of code (for SOLID or for any other reason) as we had no test coverage. So the code grew worse and worse to maintain over time.

We didn't need to refactor in my first job, as code was already SOLID, but we could have easily refactored and used the good unit test code coverage to ensure no regression.

It's like magic: to those who believe no proof is required; to those who don't believe no proof will ever be enough.

Let's put it like this: you want to work somewhere with code that is horrendously hard to understand, horrible to maintain, where devs leave as code is so poor, and where bugs are rampant or you prefer the opposite ? Code for the latter, always, whether SOLID  or not, but IMHO SOLID with unit tests will make achieving this so much easier in the long run.