# Weird function call like syntax

Tags: c++

I have come across this toplevel function in a *C++* file.
So my questions are:

1. What exactly is the `smt2::parser` type declaration doing there?
2. What is this feature called?
3. How is different from a regular call to `p(ctx, is, interactive);`?

Here's the code:

```
bool parse_smt2_commands(cmd_context & ctx, std::istream & is, bool interactive) {
    smt2::parser p(ctx, is, interactive);
    return p();
}
```

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find the definition(s) of `p()` with grep so far. I'll update the post when I find the definitions (tracking down the headers includes manually can take a while).

Comment: look for the function call operator in smt2::parser. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349867/how-can-it-be-useful-to-overload-the-function-call-operator

Comment: That's a C++-style object initialization.

Comment: That's an object instantiation followed by a call to `smt2::parser::operator()`.

Comment: smt2::parser is a type.  p is an instance.  The (ctx, is, interactive) are the args to construct p.

Comment: Also, OP should have read a beginner tutorial. This is too basic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Instance Initialization Syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372665/c-instance-initialization-syntax)

Comment: Yes gang, `p` is an object that is instantiated in the middle line of the code snippet. What is happening in the last line of the code snippet?

Comment: @KateGregory That's not the line OP is asking about...

Comment: I agree with @Kate Gregory. It appears to me that smt2::parser 'class' requires an explicit constructor then a default constructor. The object may have some sort of internal state. Bad class, but that's the interface.

Comment: @KeithSmith There's no default constructor involved in this code whatsoever. Kate was only right in that `p()` invokes `stm2::parser::operator()`, but that is **not** the line that OP is curious of, nor does it call its default constructor.

Comment: OP hasn't asked about the last line because "I haven't been able to find the definition(s) of p() with grep so far" but I am sure it was included for a reason.

Comment: Yes. I pulled the trigger too soon. @H2CO3 (are you a chemist?) and @Kate Gregory are correct, `p()` is an overloaded operator, not a constructor. Need more speed, less haste.

Comment: @KeithSmith No problem. No, I'm not a chemist (I *will* be a bionics engineer, though. My name is related to something else ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a little difficult to tell directly.  But what I imagine is going on is `smt2::parser` is the name of a class or struct type.  The line

```
stm2::parser p(ctx,is,interactive);
```

calls the constructor of that class/struct.  The class defined by `stm2::parser` likely overloaded the `()` operator.  I found [a tutorial](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/cplr327.htm) with more information about operator overloading for function calls.

Comment: @Kate Gregory, Thanks for the edit.  That made the answer much more readable.

Answer (score 3):

In the code provided in the OP, `p` is an object of type `smt2::parser`. It calls a constructor that takes three arguments. `p()` calls an overloaded operator (probably `operator()()`) that returns a bool.

Here's an example:

```
class Test {
public:
Test(int i, char j, bool k) {
}
~Test() { }

bool operator()() const {
return true;
}
};
```

In this case, we simply call the operator on a temporary to demonstrate what is happening.

```
int main() {
std::cout << Test(1, 'a', true)(); // 1
return 0;
}
```